# export requrie got empty object using node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have server.js and data.js, they are at the same level.

I do

```
var data = [{"some":"data"}];
module.exports = data;
```

and in server.js I do

`var data = require('./data'); console.log(data);`

I got `{}` ? what's wrong?

Comment: Code works fine for me. Possibly a typo? Perhaps you misspelled `module.exports'?

Comment: works for me as well. `node server ... [ { some: 'data' } ]`

Comment: @Trott opps export has 's'.